# how to get resboseBody message when login credential wrong in anuglar

Tags: angular, api

In my web App there is a login page and i have to call an api to log. there is no problem when i enter correct credential to api. but if enter wrong credential , i can't gets response body . I tried to access response body for wrong credential , there is a message that 'invalid credential'

```
 this.authService.login(this.formGroup.value).subscribe(result=>{
          if(result.succeeded){
            console.log(result);
           
           // alert(result.jwToken);
           
            // this.router.navigate(['./navbar/orderDetails']);
          }
          
          if(!result.succeeded) {

            alert('password credentials')
            alert(result.message);
          }
      
  
        }
```

api service

```
  login(data: any):Observable<Welcome4>  {
    const headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET');
    headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');

 //  return this.http.post(`${baseUrl}api/Account/authenticate`,data ) ;
   

        return this.http.post<Welcome4>(`api/Account/authenticate`,data ).pipe(
     
         catchError(this.errorHandler)
       

        ) ;
   
  } 

   
  errorHandler(error: HttpErrorResponse) {
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      // A client-side or network error occurred. Handle it accordingly.
      console.error('An error occurred:', error.error.message);
    } else {
      // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
      // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong,
      console.error(
        `Backend returned code ${error.message}, ` +
        `body was: ${error.message}`);
    }
    // return an observable with a user-facing error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happened; please try again later.');
  }
```

response body for wrong password

Response body

```
Download
{
  "Succeeded": false,
  "Message": "Invalid Credentials for 'devmendis@eworkit.it'.",
  "Errors": null,
  "Data": null,
  "JWToken": null
}
```

[image]

Comment: i tried it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

First of all, from the screen you had attached, the problem is on a component that you did not inject into the module.

And for the error, you are just throwing an error, but there is not any subscription that handles it.

So in order the throw the alert you have to:

#### Component

```js
 this.authService.login(this.formGroup.value).subscribe({
  next: result =>{
          if(result.succeeded){
            console.log(result);
            // alert(result.jwToken);
            // this.router.navigate(['./navbar/orderDetails']);
          }
        },
  error: error => {
    // You will enter here if there any `Error` throwed 
    alert('password credentials')
    alert(erorr);
  }
});
```

Your `error` inside the `subscribe` method is actually the error thrown from the `catchError` so the actual value is *`Something bad happened; please try again later.`*

Hope you have a more clear idea of how to handle errors.
You can have more details from the official Angular guides to [handling error](https://Something%20bad%20happened;%20please%20try%20again%20later.)